# How to use an array of elements multiple times in React? (unique keys)

Tags: reactjs, key

Given an array of colours I have mapped to an array of option elements to fill a select element. Each option has a unique key but I can only use the mapped array once else the keys will no longer be unique. How can I get around this without something over the top?

```
const colours=[ 
  {name:'red',hex:'ff0000',id:'4855r234'}, 
  {name:'green',hex:'00ff00',id:'1324855g'}, 
  {name:'blue',hex:'0000ff',id:'b324899'} 
] 

const colourOptions=colours.map(colour => 
  <option value={colour.hex} key={colour.id}>{colour.name}</option> 
) 

return ( 
  <form>
    <select name='shirt'>{colourOptions}</select>
    <select name='hat'>{colourOptions}</select> 
  </form> 
)
```

This gives an "Encountered two children with the same key" warning as obviously I am repeating the same keys. I could write a function which returns a new map each time with randomised keys but this feels like an ugly solution, I wanted to know what is considered the best approach?

Note:This is a minimal example, I have left out all of the controlled component code for the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem is to return a different id from the parent and the code will look like this:

```
const colors=[ 
      {name:'red',hex:'ff0000',id:'4855r234'}, 
      {name:'green',hex:'00ff00',id:'1324855g'}, 
      {name:'blue',hex:'0000ff',id:'b324899'} 
   ] 
   const colorOptions = (color) => {
      return <option value={color.hex} key={color.id}>{color.name}</option>
   };

   return (
      <form>
         <select name="shirt">
            {colors.map((color) => colorOptions(color))}
         </select>
         <select name="hat">
            {colors.map((color) => colorOptions(color))}
         </select>
      </form>
   );
```

Comment: Thank you, can you explain WHY this works, in my head this is almost identical to what I was doing before except now we run map twice (once per select), how are the keys different?

Comment: keys are no different, each map has its own keys, in the old code there was one map and pass to it the same keys and in this case a problem with duplicating keys will occur, and in the new code we have two map and in this case there will be no problem if you pass the same key.
In short, (each map should have its own keys)

Comment: Brilliant thank you for the explanation. I tried a version prior to your suggestion with a function that returned a map but took a string to add to the key, that still gave the warning even though the keys were different between selects.